# Extracting a string from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe

The database I'm working on for a school project has a column named "production_countries."

```
print(df_movies['production_countries'][0] + '\n' +
        df_movies['production_countries'][1] + '\n' +
        df_movies['production_countries'][99]     )
```

The result:

```
[{"iso_3166_1": "US", "name": "United States of America"}, {"iso_3166_1": "GB", "name": "United Kingdom"}]
[{"iso_3166_1": "US", "name": "United States of America"}]
[{"iso_3166_1": "DE", "name": "Germany"}, {"iso_3166_1": "US", "name": "United States of America"}]
```

When I prompt for `info()`

```
df_movies['production_countries'].info

<bound method Series.info of 0       [{"iso_3166_1": "US", "name": "United States o... <br>
1       [{"iso_3166_1": "US", "name": "United States o...
2       [{"iso_3166_1": "GB", "name": "United Kingdom"...
3       [{"iso_3166_1": "US", "name": "United States o...
4       [{"iso_3166_1": "US", "name": "United States o...
...                        <br>
4797    [{"iso_3166_1": "MX", "name": "Mexico"}, {"iso...
4798                                                   []
4799    \{"iso_3166_1": "US", "name": "United States o...
4800    [{"iso_3166_1": "US", "name": "United States o...
4801    [{"iso_3166_1": "US", "name": "United States o...
Name: production_countries, Length: 4802, dtype: object>
```

I'm trying to create a new column that will only contain the first abbreviation for the country.

Example:

```
df_movies[countries][0] is going to contain 'US'

df_movies[countries][2] is going to hold 'GB'
```

---

Input:

```
country=df_movies['production_countries'][99][17:19] 

print(country)
```

Output:

```
DE
```

When working on a single value, my logic seems solid, but when I tried to run this cycle to iter through the different values of  'production_countries' and assign the wanted value to 'countries', I got an error.

```
for i in df_movies['production_countries']:
    country =df_movies['production_countries'][i][17:19]
    df_movies['countries'][i]=country


df_movies['countries']
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[83], line 3
      1 #country=df_movies['production_countries'][99][17:19]
      2 for i in df_movies['production_countries']:
----> 3     country =df_movies['production_countries'][i][17:19]
      4     df_movies['countries'][i]=country
      7 df_movies['countries']

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:981, in Series.__getitem__(self, key)
    978     return self._values[key]
    980 elif key_is_scalar:
--> 981     return self._get_value(key)
    983 if is_hashable(key):
    984     # Otherwise index.get_value will raise InvalidIndexError
    985     try:
    986         # For labels that don't resolve as scalars like tuples and frozensets

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:1089, in Series._get_value(self, label, takeable)
   1086     return self._values[label]
   1088 # Similar to Index.get_value, but we do not fall back to positional
-> 1089 loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
   1090 return self.index._get_values_for_loc(self, loc, label)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py:395, in RangeIndex.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
    393             raise KeyError(key) from err
    394     self._check_indexing_error(key)
--> 395     raise KeyError(key)
    396 return super().get_loc(key, method=method, tolerance=tolerance)

KeyError: '[{"iso_3166_1": "US", "name": "United States of America"}, {"iso_3166_1": "GB", "name": "United Kingdom"}]'
```

My questions are:

A- What am I doing wrong?

B- Is there a tutorial/class/video that can explain better the topic I'm having an issue with?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though each entry of the 'production countries' column is a string corresponding to a list of dictionaries. With that said, you can use [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) or the marginally safer [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to do something like the following.

```
from ast import literal_eval

def get_country(entry):
    return literal_eval(entry)[0]["iso_3166_1"]

df_movies['countries'] = df_movies['production_countries'].apply(get_country)
```

Answer (score 4):

It really helps to debug your code, for example print out the values of variables before the error occurs. In your case `print(i)` inside the `for` loop will show that `i` is equal to `[{"iso_3166_1": "US", "name": "United States of America"}, {"iso_3166_1": "GB", "name": "United Kingdom"}]`, not `0` as you are probably expecting.

You can iterate through range from 0 to length of your dataframe:
`for i in range(df_movies.shape[0])`

But then you will have a problem here: `df_movies['countries'][i]=country`, because you don't have a column with that name yet.

The best way to do what you want is to apply a function to a whole column, receiving another column with results.

```
df_movies['countries'] = df_movies['production_countries'].apply(lambda x: x[17:19])
print(df_movies)
```

Output:

```
                                production_countries countries
0  [{"iso_3166_1": "US", "name": "United States o...        US
1  [{"iso_3166_1": "US", "name": "United States o...        US
2  [{"iso_3166_1": "DE", "name": "Germany"}, {"is...        DE
```

UPD: in [Ben's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2476977/ben-grossmann) comment there's another valid approach that looks even nicer leading to the same result

```
df_movies['countries'] = df_movies['production_countries'].str[17:19]
```

Comment: A marginally nicer (I think) and better-performing approach would be to use `df_movies['production_countries'].str[17:19]` instead of apply

Comment: Indeed, you're right, thanks! Added this to the answer.

Comment: very clean and performant approach while I was propably overthinking. But is the result not incomplete by only slicing the string for the first contry abbreviation? The name `production_countries` implies that there may be several and the sample data shows entries with two countries.

Comment: ok, nvmd. She asked specifically for _only contain the first abbreviation_

Answer (score 0):

First of all let me explain what your error is about.

If you look at your error:

```py
KeyError  # means, you used a Key which is not recognised
      2 for i in df_movies['production_countries']:
----> 3     country =df_movies['production_countries'][i][17:19]  # the key in question is i
      4     df_movies['countries'][i]=country
      7 df_movies['countries']
```

you might realize that you are looping over all the elements in the column `'production_countries'`. Your `info()` call showed you that there are 4802 entries in this column of dtype: object. This means that `i` is not a key to reference a entry in the column but rather the entry itself.

---

Now what you can do:

It seems like every `i` is a list of dictionaries. Your example output from the database (which seems to be a dict itself) prints first a list of two dictionaries US and GB, then a list of only one dictionary representing US...

So lets change the loop to drill down into this structure like so:

```py
# loop over every entry in column production_countries
for entry in df_movies['production_countries']:
    # loop over every production country, since entry is a list and contain more than one item
    for dictionary in entry:
        # the abbreviation is stored in the dict with the key iso_3166_1
        print(dictionary['iso_3166_1'])
```

This way you get every abbreviation without slicing a string and you do not need to store it in a new column since it would be redundant.

But if your data is really a string rather than a list do something like this:

```py
from ast import literal_eval

# new list for only the lists of country abbreviations
countries = []

# now i is the index or line of the entry in the column
for i, entry in enumerate(df_movies['production_countries']):
    # append empty list for the country abbreviation
    countries.append([])
    for dictionary in literal_eval(entry):
        # fill list with country abbreviations
        countries[i].append(dictionary['iso_3166_1'])

# new column with only abbreviations
df_movies['countries'] = countries
```